# On click on specific button open another page and show specific value in drop down list

Tags: javascript, html, css

Below are my html code. 
I'm opening `page 2` from `page 1` and there is a dropdown on `page 2`.

`Page 1`...

```
<html>

<body>


<form id="myForm">

<br>
  <input type="button" value="Volvo">   >//open page2 and show volvo in dropdown
  <input type="button" value="saab">    >//open page2 and show saab in dropdown
  <input type="button" value="opel">    >//open page2 and show opel in dropdown
</form>



</body>
</html>
```

`Page 2`...

```
<html>

<body>


<form id="myForm">          <-- form to select option -->

<select id="a">
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>   >///if click on volvo button show this
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>    >//if click on saab button show this
  <option value="opel">Opel</option>   >//if click on opel button show this

 </select>

</form>

</body>
</html>
```

If I click to open `page 2` then show `opel` in the dropdown

Comment: page 2 has the dropdown list

Comment: how are you redirecting to page2? Can you show the code for that?

Answer (score 1):

This solution is a pure-JavaScript solution.  It could be improved if you have server-side code, but, I don't see that in your question, so, let's do JS only.

***Page1: The Form Page***

On page1, make sure to set your form to `GET` *and* set a `name` property of your inputs.  `GET` allows the form parameters to be accessible to JS and `name` is necessary on any input element of any form..

```
<form id="myForm" method="get">
<input type="button" value="Volvo" name="button">
```

***Page2: The Page that Form Page Goes To***

Then, when you submit the form, you'll get to page2, and the full URL will look like: `example.com/page2?button=volvo`.  At page2, *after defining your input elements*, run the following JavaScript...

```
const urlParams = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);
const myParam = urlParams.get('button');
document.getElementById('a').value = myParam;
```

This will cause the proper select parameter to be selected.

[**100% Full Working Demo with "Saab" Preselected.**](https://jsbin.com/vuziquv/5/edit?html,console,output)

Comment: I have added in page1 `<form id="myForm" method="get"> <input type="button" onclick="window.location.href='test2.html'" value="volvo" name="button">` and add below code in page 2`<html>
<body>

  
  <select id="a">
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="opel">Opel</option>
   
</select>



</body>
</html>

<script>
const urlParams = new URLSearchParams(window.location.href);
const myParam = urlParams.get('button');
document.getElementById('a').value = myParam;
</script>` But dropdown is showing blank on click.

Comment: my url is this coming  http://127.0.0.1:59112/test2.html?button=saab but dropdown list is showing blank

Comment: Hi, Saurabh Garg: `127.0.0.1` is a local address, nobody can connect to that but you.  Here's a full working demo that's basically a copy/paste of the above code: https://jsbin.com/vuziquv/5/edit?html,console,output  I have hardcoded the value to "saab" because GET params do not work with JSBin.

Comment: @SaurabhGarg - It's a bit hard to debug `GET` param issues without your own site, so, take a look at a [Browsing Page with Customizable Per-Page Counts](https://www.revoltlib.com/people/view.php?action=browse&perpage=20).  You can set "Results per page" (or `perpage`) to 20, 30, 40, etc., click "update", and it'll remember the last selection.  If you have a working online demo, I can look at that too.